# For every partition $\pi$ of a fixed integer $n$, $\sum{F(\pi)}=\sum{G(\pi)}$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, integer-partitions

I need to prove the following question.

For every partition $\pi$ of a fixed integer $n$, define $F(\pi)$=number of occurrences of 1 as a summand, and $G(\pi)$=no. of distinct summands in the partition. Prove that $\sum{F(\pi)}=\sum{G(\pi)}$.

I was trying to solve this taking an example of 5 with Ferrers graph but not getting how to prove it.

Comment: *Hint:*  dual partition.  (Draw Young diagrams to see the bijection.)

Comment: Can you please provide some more hint.

Comment: @SammyBlack: Could you elaborate on the hint? It is certainly not true that $F(\pi)$ equals $G(\pi^*)$.

Comment: @Shahab, you're certainly correct.  I misread one of the functions.  I'm not so sure how to proceed now.  Perhaps look at the generating function in two different ways and equate coefficients?

Comment: It can be shown that $\sum F(\pi)=p(0)+\cdots p(n-1)$. I am having trouble proving that the RHS equals $\sum G(\pi)$.

Comment: @Shahab, see my answer below. The argument (not due to me) shows that $\sum G(\pi)=p(0)+\cdots p(n-1)$.

Answer (score 1):

The following proof uses ordinary generating functions (bivariate). The partition generating function where ones are marked is
$$Q_1(z, u) = \frac{1}{1-uz} \prod_{k\ge 2} \frac{1}{1-z^k}.$$
If we want to sum the occurrences of one as a summand for all partitions of $n$ we need to compute
$$\left.\frac{d}{du} Q_1(z, u) \right|_{u=1}
= \left. -1\times \frac{1}{(1-uz)^2} \times -z \times 
\prod_{k\ge 2} \frac{1}{1-z^k} \right|_{u=1}
= \frac{z}{1-z} \prod_{k\ge 1} \frac{1}{1-z^k}.$$
On the other hand, marking distinct summands looks like this:
$$Q_2(z,u) = \prod_{k\ge 1}\left(1 + u z^k + u z^{2k} + u z^{3k} + \cdots\right).$$
Once more differentiating and setting $u=1$ gives this time
$$\left.\frac{d}{du} Q_2(z, u) \right|_{u=1}
= \left.\prod_{k\ge 1}\left(1 + u z^k + u z^{2k} + u z^{3k} + \cdots\right)
\times \sum_{k\ge 1}
\frac{z^k + z^{2k} + z^{3k} + \cdots}
{1 + u z^k + u z^{2k} + u z^{3k} + \cdots}\right|_{u=1}
\\= \prod_{k\ge 1}\frac{1}{1-z^k} \sum_{k\ge 1} \frac{z^k/(1-z^k)}{1/(1-z^k)}
= \prod_{k\ge 1}\frac{1}{1-z^k} \sum_{k\ge 1} z^k
= \frac{z}{1-z} \prod_{k\ge 1}\frac{1}{1-z^k}.$$
The two generating functions are exactly the same, QED.

There are similar computations at this [MSE link I](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/587471/number-of-1s-among-all-partitions-of-an-integer) and this [MSE link II](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/543561/partitions-of-n-into-distinct-odd-and-even-parts-proof).

Answer (score 1):

A counting argument attributed to [Richard Stanley](https://mathoverflow.net/users/2807/richard-stanley) appears [here](http://www.qbyte.org/puzzles/p056s.html).

Briefly, it goes like this:

$$\displaystyle\sum_{\pi\,\vdash n} {F(\pi)}=\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n p(n-i)\textrm,$$

because $p(n-i)$ is the number of partitions of $n$ with at least $i$ ones. The sum counts the number of partitions with $k$ ones $k$ times: once in $p(n-1)$, once in $p(n-2)$, and so on up to one final time in $p(n-k)$.

Then $\displaystyle\sum{G(\pi)}$ is shown to be the same thing by a clever observation.

Let $True(P)$ have value $1$ if $P$ is true and $0$ if $P$ is false, and let $H(i)$ be the number of partitions of $n$ that contain (at least one) $i$. Then

$$\sum_{\pi\,\vdash n}{G(\pi)}=\sum_{\pi\,\vdash n}\sum_{i=1}^nTrue\left(\pi \textrm{ contains an }i \right) = \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{\pi\,\vdash n}True\left(\pi \textrm{ contains an }i \right) = \sum_{i=1}^n H(i)\textrm.$$

The observation that $H(i)=p(n-i)$ completes the proof.