# How to write $1-x-x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6-x^7 \cdots$ as a power series representation

Tags: probability, power-series, generating-functions

How can I write $1-x-x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6-x^7 ....$ as a power series representation (i.e., a neat fraction such as $\frac{1}{1-x}$.

This stems from $\binom{\text{number of partitions of }n}{\text{into an even number of parts}}-\binom{\text{number of partitions of }n}{\text{into an odd number of parts}}$.

I've been pondering this for a while, yet can't seem to think of any ways to solve this. Any hints?

EDIT: The polynominal with a few extra terms i: $1-x-x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6-x^7+2x^8-2x^9+2x^{10}-2x^{11}+3x^{12}-3x^{13}+3x^{14} ...$

Comment: What is the pattern here?

Comment: Would you mind writing out a few more terms to make a pattern more apparent

Comment: @vadim123: I'm not sure if there is any specific pattern. It was originally $\binom{\text{number of partitions of }n}{\text{into an even number of parts}}-\binom{\text{number of partitions of }n}{\text{into an odd number of parts}}$, but I found some terms.

Comment: @TylerHG: Sure, I don't mind. :)  You can also reference my comment below.

Comment: @TylerHG Ok. Added some more. It seems to alternate (positive, negative). Also, for the first 8 terms, the coefficient is 1. For the next 4 terms, the coefficient is 2. I'm assuming that for the next 2 terms after that, the coefficient is 3.

Comment: @TylerHG: Actually, never mind... the recent terms I just added are a counterexample to what I originally thought.

Comment: It might be worthwhile to see of the terms end up looking like $$a_n=(-1)^nnx^n$$ as this can be summed directly. Then to get a formula for the full series one could subtract off the first few terms. Edit: nevermind for my comment too after yours came up

Comment: @TylerHG: I did find this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/543561/partitions-of-n-into-distinct-odd-and-even-parts-proof . see 1.

Comment: This seems to be the number of partitions minus twice the number of distinct partitions of $n$.  It also seems to be number of partitions of $n$ into distinct odd parts multiplied by a sign based on parity.

Answer (score 1):

This appears in the [oeis](http://oeis.org/A081362), wherein it is given that the generating function is $$\prod_{k>0}1-x^{2k-1}=\prod_{k>0}\frac{1}{1+x^k}$$
There are also many references there, I highly recommend that link.

Comment: by k>0 , do you mean that it works for all k including 1 to infinity?

Comment: That's correct; the products are each from $k=1$ on up.

Comment: It's not 'works for' - you need _all_ those terms in the product.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki yes, that is what i meant to say, yet couldn't word it correctly.

Comment: @vadim123: After using that: how would I turn $\frac{1}{(1+x)(1-x)(1+x^2)(1-x^2)(1+x^3)(1-x^3)....}$ into a generating function power series again (for powers past 15)?

Comment: Each of those is a geometric series.

Comment: @vadim123: would it be: $1+x^2+2x^4+3x^6+4x^8+5x^{10}+7x^{12}....$ ?

Comment: @Vadim123: for $k = 2$ I got as LHS = $\frac{-(x-1)^2}{x}$ and RHS $\frac{1}{1+x}$.

Comment: You need to take the product over all $k$, not just $k=2$.