# Double Product in the proof of partitions of $n$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics, generating-functions, integer-partitions

So I  am supposed to show that the number of partitions of $n$ for which no part appears more than twice is equal to the number of partitions of n for which no part is divisible by 3. and there is one part which I cannot easily show mathematically (That part was found in the penultimate answer to [Partitions of $n$ into distinct odd and even parts proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/543561/partitions-of-n-into-distinct-odd-and-even-parts-proof?rq=1)). As said I understand the proof but there is this small algebraic expression I don´t understand, how they are equal.

$$\prod_{k\ge 0} \frac{1}{1-z^{3k+1}} \prod_{k\ge 0} \frac{1}{1-z^{3k+2}}=$$
$$=\prod_{k\ge 1} \frac{1-z^{3k}}{1-z^k}$$

I would appreciate any kind of help?

Comment: Multiply both sides with $\prod_{k \geqslant 1} \frac{1}{1 - z^{3k}}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If in $$\prod_{k\ge 1}{1-z^k} $$
you split $k$ as $3j, \; 3j+1,\; 3j+2$, you can easily arrive to check the identity